# How do I properly format this object in powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm trying to create an object with information about all the drives that looks something like this:

```
[
  {"letter": "C:", "volumeName": "Disk C", "brand": "INTEL ModelName", "mediaType" : "Fixed hard disk media"},
  {"letter": "D:", "volumeName": "Disk D", "brand": "Seagate ModelName", "mediaType" : "Fixed hard disk media"},
]
```

But the following powershell command produces not only poorly formated results but also an object for each property of the 1st disk instead of putting all the properties of each disk in an object:

```
% {New-Object PSObject -Property @{'caption' =$(wmic logicaldisk get caption $_); 'volumeName' =$(wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName $_); 'brand' =$(wmic diskdrive get caption $_); 'format' =$(wmic diskdrive get mediaType $_);}} | format-list
```

### Update

I tried using this command instead:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk | % {New-Object PSObject -Property @{'caption' =$($_.caption); 'volumeName' =$($_.VolumeName); 'brand' =$(); 'format' =$()}} | format-list
```

which gives me half of the values

```
caption    : C:
brand      :
format     :
volumeName : SSD

caption    : D:
brand      :
format     :
volumeName : Disk D

caption    : E:
brand      :
format     :
volumeName : Disk e

caption    : F:
brand      :
format     :
volumeName :
```

Comment: What do you have before the `%`?

Comment: @EBGreen nothing. There was just another command like `wmic logicaldisk...` but I removed it, since I didn't know how to get the results from it and put them into the object, so I just execute each command right in the object properties

Comment: Well, `%` is the alias for the `forEach-Object` command so that is just silly right off the bat since you are not passing it a collection to iterate over. Your first step will be to put something in front of that that will generate the collection that you need. I would suggest `Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk | `

Comment: @EBGreen thanks, I tried that, and it works, but now I can only get the values from `Win32_LogicalDisk` and the other 2 properties are empty. Do you know how to fill in the other 2? Those values come from the function called `diskdrive` when the first 2 are from `logicaldisk`

Comment: Well, you whould need to use `Get-WMIObject Win32_DiskDrive` you would also need to link the two in some fashion. Also be aware that Win32_LogicalDisk will get information for network mapped drives as well as physical drives and that there is no way to get the Win32_DiskDrive information fro those without querying the server where the drive physically resides.

Comment: @EBGreen ah, good to know, I'll have to filter out local disks! thanks for the help, I'm gonna try linking them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working example how you can link disks with volumes using disk partitions. The matter is that volumes are not linked to disks directly, but only via partitions

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | 
Select-Object DeviceID, Model, MediaType |
ForEach-Object { 
    $o = $_
    Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" |
    Select-Object @{ N='Model'; E={$o.Model} }, 
                  @{ N='MediaType'; E={$o.MediaType} }, 
                  DeviceID
} |
ForEach-Object {
    $o2 = $_
    Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition" |
    Select-Object @{ N='Letter'; E={$_.Name} }, 
                  VolumeName, 
                  @{ N='MediaType'; E={$o2.MediaType} }, 
                  @{ N='Model'; E={$o2.Model} }
}
```